# Opencart exclude products or cagegory from specials page

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to exclude some products from specials page, because I have the a product "day dress product x" and "evening dress product x"  it's the same product but different categories... And they  are next to each other .. 2 products that looks the same only the name difference, so i want to exclude one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OpenCart don't use any category id in database query to get the special products, so you have to do it from special controller, go to special.php under this location

```
catalog/controller/product/special.php
```

then find `foreach ($results as $result) {`
and add this code in next line

```
$excludeProducts = array(10, 20, 30, 14, 15);

if (in_array( $result['product_id'], $excludeProducts )) {
    continue;
}
```

Where `$excludeProducts`  has product id's that you wants to exclude. You can also make vQmod file for it if you are familiar with vQmod. Its best way to modify the core files of OpenCart. But if you wants to exclude any specific category then you have to modify the DB query under Model.

Comment: and for multiple product i just put =='y' =='z' ?

Comment: @LiviuDaniel Updated my answer for multiple products, you have to just put the excluded id in ($excludeProducts ) array.

Comment: @LiviuDaniel Is it working ? If so then please mark it a valid answer :)

Comment: yes you cand do it withe array but i used this foreach ($results as $result) {
   if ($result['product_id'] == '894' || $result['product_id'] == '892' and so one..